# Is it possible to assign a specific node to create container with docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When creating new containers, it follows the swarm's strategy to select a node

I don't want to issue the command against the node directly if it have to work on that specific one.

Is there a way to tell swarm to work on a specific node?

---

***UPDATE***

According to @DAXaholic 's reply, by default daemon option `Lable` can be the callable tag.

So, I edit `/etc/default/docker`, add `--label` to `DOCKER_OPTS`.

After restart services, node is able to called by specific label values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that with [filters](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/filter/#/use-a-constraint-filter)
So the idea is essentially you give your nodes tags that describe them like 'node-with-gpu' or something like that.
There is also a default tag 'node' which you can use to filter for a specific node

So an example to run Redis on `node1` could look like this

```
$ docker tcp://<manager_ip:manager_port> run -d --name redis1 -e
constraint:node==node1 redis
```